# If I pass the "Life in the UK" test now, how long does it last, for the purpose of applying for British citizenship?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

I've been in UK for 4 years, and as far as I understand it, I need a minimum of 2 more years to get the citizenship.

One on the prerequisites to be able to ask for it, is that I pass the "Life in the UK" test.

I'm thinking of doing it now, so I don't have to think about it anymore until I'll apply for the citizenship.

The question is: if I pass it today, will the result be valid in 2+ years from now?

---

I see that at the page on [*Apply for citizenship if you have indefinite leave to remain or 'settled status'*](https://www.gov.uk/apply-citizenship-indefinite-leave-to-remain) I see that one of the eligibility criteria is

> have passed the life in the UK test

which doesn't include "in the last X months/years", but at the same time it doesn't include "any time in the past", so I'd like to confirm where the truth lies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [full version](https://www.gov.uk/life-in-the-uk-test/print) of the "Life in the UK Test" presentation contains this:

> **When you do not need to take the test**
>
> You do not need to take the test if you:
>
> - are under 18
> - are 65 or older
> - **have passed it before** - for example, if you’re applying to become a citizen and already passed it as part of your settlement application *(emphasis added)*
> - have a long-term physical or mental condition - you must provide either a form or letter from a doctor confirming your physical or mental condition

The words "have passed it before" after the third bullet point are unqualified.

Thus, passing the test once at any time in the past is sufficient.